# Atom with prettier, eslint and airbnb style guide for React development

Tags: atom-editor, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier

Does anyone know how to properly setup eslint with prettier in Atom editor?
I wanted to use airbnb presets, but when I check ESlint integration in prettier settings, after I save my file, I have trailing commas after some functions, and other strange issues. How to set it up to make prettier respect airbnb rules after file save?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint

From the description:

**The problem**

The `fix` feature of `eslint` is pretty great and can auto-format/fix much of your code according to your ESLint config. `prettier` is a more powerful automatic formatter. One of the nice things about prettier is how opinionated it is. Unfortunately it's not opinionated enough and/or some opinions differ from my own. So after prettier formats the code, I start getting linting errors.

**This solution**

This formats your code via `prettier`, and then passes the result of that to `eslint --fix`. This way you can get the benefits of `prettier`'s superior formatting capabilities, but also benefit from the configuration capabilities of `eslint`.

> For files with an extension of .css, .less, .scss, or .json this only
>   runs prettier since eslint cannot process those.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that prettier-eslint for Atom has been depreciated and prettier-atom doesn't support the Airbnb style guide.

Comment: Digging this up again: Is this still accurate?